# Can you recommend literature - easy/gentle/for self-study/introductory... - for the following topics...?

Tags: foundations, proof-theory, constructive-mathematics, meta-math, reverse-math

I am looking for literature that is as self-explanatory, easy, gentle, readable to the beginner, suitable for self-study, etc.. as possible, in the following fields.
(I mean the mathematical part as well as the philosophical)

- constructive mathematics
- reverse mathematics
- foundations (frameworks, formal systems, basic ideas/concepts) of mathematics

I have a few years of professional training in 'mainstream' mathematics, but its been some years since then. I've done an introduction to logic and looked a bit into proof theory.

I would be interested in your suggestions as well as (also brief) explanations why you favor that particular work.

Thanks in advance,

Ettore

Comment: On the topic of the axiomatic foundations of set theory, there is  the  small introductory "Set Theory" by Suppes, which could serve as a text at  1st-year college level, and includes some discussion on motivations and history.  (It might be available  from Dover Publications, which for generations has been a great source for cheap re-prints in math & science.). For fun with the countably infinite, see "Stories About Sets" by Vilenkin (V'lenkin). I have not read "Naive Set Theory" by Halmos, but I know it  has a continuing popularity.

Comment: What is reverse mathematics?

Comment: Peter Smith wrote an excellent article on exactly this topic; books are recommended based on your own perceived competency:
https://www.logicmatters.net/tyl/

Comment: Stillwell's recent book on reverse mathematics is really accessible

Comment: @DanielWainfleet : Thans a lot Daniel! Approaches to set theory might be something I want to engage in now for foundational interests, although for now I think I am more looking for a work that compares different foundational possibilities, not necessarily all lying in sets, however I might have a look into your recommendations.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet : As far as reverse math is concerned, I am not the right person to give you an introduction now and here, I think. You will find enough online, I personally found talk by Harvey Friedman very inspiring, you can find some of them on youtube.

Comment: @DanielMak : Thanks, thats really comprehensive. To be honest I don't know what to do with it at the moment, but it might help me in the future.

Comment: @MarkS. I will have a look into it and may buy it, thanks.